# Can someone help me translate this?

Tags: translation, word

This reverse painted glass ball was made for me 18 years ago before I came to the US.I have no knowledge of the language but I would like to know what it says. I tried looking it up but no websites would give me a clear answer. It has my name on it above in English so I’m not sure if it says that or something else below it in Chinese.
Thank you lots!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Chinese name that sounds the same as your English name.

Comment: Ahh okay, also wondering, is it just two characters or three? It seems like two but it looks as if the first one could be split into two (like one on top one on bottom)

Comment: Just two characters.

Answer (score 1):

李 = Lǐ

丽 = Lì

You are right, 李 is made up of two words, 木, (wood), and 子, (child, son)

李 is the second most common Chinese surname, with a World wide population of around 100 million. As a word it means a "plum", 李子

丽, meaning "beautiful", "pretty" is traditionally a most common personal name for Chinese females.

So there is no doubt that 李丽 is a female name, and in your case, a transliteration of "Lily"

For the origin of 李, you may want to read:-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_(surname_%E6%9D%8E)

Comment: I love that! I’ll definitely be reading up on it now.  Thank you so much!